# What would the climate of Verkhoyansk and Oymyakon be like if the mountains surrounding it were high as the Himalayas

Tags: climate, geography

Although both contain the northern poles of cold, they also tend to get somewhat warm in the summer, more than in some places of similar latitudes (according to what I have seen at least). I would like to propose two scenarios, one in which both the Verkhoyansk and Oymyakon plateaus are completely enclosed by very tall (or high) mountains similar in size to the Himalayas or at least like the andes. My second scenario is to surround all of the plateaus except with a small overture to the Okhotsk sea where mountains are at a lower level. My goal is to make portions of the plateaus, or at least Oymyakon, possibly as habitable as Poland. Adding that the mountains in coastal Khabarovsk are as tall in order to make climatic influences from the Siberian high lower.

Answer (score 3):

**It will be a cold desert**

If an area is surrounded by high mountains, it will be more prone to seasonal changes of temperatures. Coldest and hottest temperatures would not likely to change much, but the place will be consistently warm in the summer and consistently very cold in winter. In addition, mountains will block most of the moisture coming into the region, making the place much drier.